# Access Terminal Commands with QGIS

Tags: python, gdal, grass-gis

I'm working with QGIS3.22 and I want to use `GRASS` and `GDAL` directly from the terminal. Primarily, this is so that I can gain a better understanding of the tools by viewing the `get-help` output (if it exists). I believe that I can install `GRASS` and `GDAL` separately to QGIS, which would work. However, I would prefer to save space by accessing the existing installations that came along with QGIS. Does anyone no how to do this? I have searched through `Program Files` and located most of the executables, but using `new-alias` on each one seems quite tedious. I've done some research into `$env:path`, but I'm not sure if this is the correct tool. Ultimately my goal is to have `QGIS` running with a pre-existing installation of the various tools that are managed separately. As I'm sure someone will point out this is a bad idea, but one I want to try. Can someone please point me in the correct direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I have exact same scenario as you and wanted to achieve the same thing. (Worth noting im on a windows machine, running OSGEO installation of QGIS).

You will need to know the path to your QGIS installation. In my case, it was D:\osgeo4w64\  (I performed the OSGEO installation, yours might be different).
In that installation there should be a bin folder or similar, which contains the gdal executibles (ogr2ogr for example).
In my instance, this path is simply D:\osgeo4W64\bin\

When I navigate to that folder, the gdal tools are now available via the cmd prompt

```
  d:\>cd osgeo4w64

d:\OSGeo4W64>cd bin

d:\OSGeo4W64\bin>ogr2ogr
Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
               [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where|@filename]
               [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>|@filename] [-dialect dialect]
               [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID] [-limit nb_features]
               [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-spat_srs srs_def] [-geomfield field]
               [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def] [-ct string]
               [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
               dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
               [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name]
               [-nlt type|PROMOTE_TO_MULTI|CONVERT_TO_LINEAR|CONVERT_TO_CURVE]
               [-dim XY|XYZ|XYM|XYZM|layer_dim] [layer [layer ...]]
```

You can add that path to your PATH system environment variable and the tools should be available from any folder. (actually, i should probably do that and check that that is the case, but 99% sure it is).

I personally haven't done this with GRASS.. However the logic will be the same, but execution I think will be different. You will need to run 'grass' program, followed by the geoprocessing tool.

eg

```
grass /path/to/grassdata/test1/PERMANENT/ --exec r.external input=basins.tiff output=basins
```

This will mean having 'grass' set to your PATH environment variable. There is good info about how to set this up and run it from here.
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/grass.html

Comment: Hi @nr_aus that worked. Thanks. For some reason I still cannot access the python implementation that comes with QGIS although everything else was fine. Any thoughts as to why this is the case. Using `get-command -name python` returns something (not `QGIS`) but `python` opens the Windows store.

Comment: so thats a slightly different setup again, but I have seen it asked in this forum, have a quick search, see what you can find.

Comment: It turns out that `QGIS` provides a few different installations of `python`. I was trying to use the wrong executable. For others the executable under `apps\Python39` was the correct one.